# Why don't Node.js ReadableStreams support reading from asynchronous sources?

Tags: node.js

I'm implementing a Readable Stream. In my `_read()` implementation, the source of the stream is a web service which requires asynchronous calls. Why doesn't `_read()` provide a `done` callback function that can be called when my asynchronous call returns?

The Transform stream and the Writable stream both support this. Why doesn't Readable? Am I just using Readable streams improperly?

```
MyReadStream.prototype._read = function() {

  doSomethingAsync('foo', function(err, result) {
     if (result) {
       this.push(result);
     } else {
       this.push(null);
     }

     // why no done() available to call like in _write()?
     // done();
  }
}
```

In my actual implementation, I don't want to call `doSomethingAsync` again until a previous call has returned. Without a `done` callback for me to use, I have to implement my own throttle mechanism.

Comment: Can't you use the `end` event? http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

Comment: that would signify that the stream is completely done reading from its source. i just want to signify that one invocation of _read() has completed reading from the source.

Comment: You are of course correct, my bad. Looking over the docs again, is a `done()` callback even necessary? Pushing onto `this`, assuming it inherits from `stream.Readable` should trigger a new read along with firing the readable event. I may be very wrong as I've only used and not implemented my own stream readers.

Answer (score 2):

`_read()` is a notification that the amount of buffered data is below the `highWaterMark`, so more data can be pulled from upstream.

`_write()` has a callback because it has to know when you're done processing the chunk. If you don't execute the callback for a long time, the `highWaterMark` may be reached and data should stop flowing in. When you execute the callback, the internal buffer can start to drain again, allowing more writes to continue.

So `_read()` doesn't need a callback because it's an advisory thing that you're free to ignore because it's just telling you the stream is able to buffer more data internally, whereas the callback in `_write()` is critical because it controls backpressure and buffering. If you need to throttle your web API calls, you may look into what the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) module has to offer, especially [`async.memoize`](https://github.com/caolan/async#memoize) and/or [`async.queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue).